# How to update source of WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, itemsource

I have a WPF ListView to wich I bind my collection. Properties of the objects in this collection are changed in a background thread. I need to update ListView when properties are changed. SourceUpdated event is not fired when I change some object's property.

P.S. Setting ItemSource to null and rebinding then is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raises the required change notification when the setter is called on your property.

```
// This is a simple customer class that 
// implements the IPropertyChange interface.
public class DemoCustomer  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // These fields hold the values for the public properties.
    private Guid idValue = Guid.NewGuid();
    private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
    private string phoneNumberValue = String.Empty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    // The constructor is private to enforce the factory pattern.
    private DemoCustomer()
    {
        customerNameValue = "Customer";
        phoneNumberValue = "(555)555-5555";
    }

    // This is the public factory method.
    public static DemoCustomer CreateNewCustomer()
    {
        return new DemoCustomer();
    }

    // This property represents an ID, suitable
    // for use as a primary key in a database.
    public Guid ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idValue;
        }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerNameValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)
            {
                this.customerNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneNumberValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
            {
                this.phoneNumberValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
            }
        }
  }
}
```

If you are instead referring to items being added/removed from the collection (which you did not mention) then you would need to make sure your collection is an `ObservableCollection<T>`

Answer (score 3):

that should be automatic, you just need to use an ObservableCollection as a container for your objects, and your object's class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (you can just implement the pattern for the properties which you want to notify the listview that there was a change)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)